# how to get check the first part if it has question mark

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I have in database values like this

```
123456789
826438758
?emailaddress1@test.com
?emailaddress2@test2.com
```

I am getting the value dynamically but I need to be able to find out if there is a ? in the value. If there is a question mark in the value I want to redirect them to some other place

I think we can do this with regex but not sure how

Comment: Are you looking for PHP or a query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (strpos($string, '?') === 0) {
  //redirect
  header("Location: http://www.example.com");
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

The `===` is important as it will return `false` when there is no question mark, and `false == 0` is true.

Comment: Dan is right, go with strpos, it will be more performant, and less confusing to the uninitiated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use the string index

```
if ($string[0] === '?') {
  echo 'header("Location: http://www.example.com");';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?

if (preg_match('#^\?#', $str)) {
    header('Location: http://google.com');
}
```